# Issue with ghostscript processing of a PDF with embedded PDF (produced with LaTeX)

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have converted [this file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/Nucleosynthesis_periodic_table.svg) to PDF using `rsvg-convert`.

I’m now embedding it within this LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{nucleosynthesis_periodic_table.pdf}
\end{document}
```

that I compile to [test_lualatex.pdf](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/attachment.cgi?id=17654) which I then process using this command: `gs -o test_output_lualatex.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress test_lualatex.pdf` (I’m normally doing this on my bigger main document, where this helps a lot reducing the PDF size —here I’m only providing a MWE). And I get this: [test_output_lualatex.pdf](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/attachment.cgi?id=17655).

Why is the output so different after ghostscript processing? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Your file, even when simplified to a single element, is exceedingly complicated. it has multiple layers of transparency, and forms,and transparency groups. Fairly clearly an SMask is going AWOL, you should report a bug.

Comment: @KenS To ghostscript or rsvg-convert?

Comment: Well Ghostscript, I don't know what rsvg-convert is.

Comment: The tool used to convert the SVG file to PDF, which could be responsible for the complexity of the initial PDF file. OK, I’ll open a bug against ghostscript then.

Comment: Reported [here](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=701181). Note that from further testing, the issue could also be in the pdfLaTeX/LuaLaTeX PDF engine, since processing with XeLaTeX, which has a different PDF engine, seems to work OK (but using XeLaTeX is not an option in my case).